# Arduino program hang in less than 4-6 hours

Tags: arduino

I have an arduino mega that monitor 18 sensors ds18b20 and also control 18 relays.

The mega is network wired and sends / receive to an mqtt server.

For some unknown reason to me it is hang after around 18-20 hours. I can see that looking on the db where node red server insert data received from mega.

I will put here the code maybe some of you experienced can spot some issue in coding...I don t se other reason for that so I guess maybe the way I wrote the code is not good...

---

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

byte mac[]    = {  0xD2, 0x33, 0xE1, 0x7E, 0xCA, 0x8D };

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 25);
IPAddress server(192, 168, 1, 10);

// Data wire is plugged into port 2 on the Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2

//Relays
#define pinC01 22
#define pinC02 23
#define pinC03 24
#define pinC04 25
#define pinC05 26
#define pinC06 27
#define pinC07 28
#define pinC08 29
#define pinC09 30
#define pinC10 31
#define pinC11 32
#define pinC12 33
#define pinC13 34
#define pinC14 35
#define pinC15 36
#define pinC16 37
#define pinRETUR 38
#define pinPOMPA 39

// Addresses of DS18B20s

uint8_t t_tur_intrare[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0xE3, 0x2A, 0x33, 0x17, 0x03, 0xED };
uint8_t t_tur[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0xA9, 0x06, 0x52, 0x17, 0x04, 0x56 };
uint8_t t_retur[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0xA9, 0x39, 0x21, 0x17, 0x04, 0x8F };
uint8_t t_c01[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x91, 0xAD, 0x53, 0x17, 0x04, 0x7A };
uint8_t t_c02[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x4F, 0xD1, 0x52, 0x17, 0x04, 0x97 };
uint8_t t_c03[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x56, 0x07, 0x53, 0x17, 0x04, 0xBB };
uint8_t t_c04[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0xE8, 0x08, 0x52, 0x17, 0x04, 0x67 };
uint8_t t_c05[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x05, 0xB0, 0x51, 0x17, 0x04, 0x38 };
uint8_t t_c06[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x12, 0xB6, 0x51, 0x17, 0x04, 0x1C };
uint8_t t_c07[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x68, 0x5D, 0x40, 0x17, 0x03, 0x73 };
uint8_t t_c08[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0xB9, 0x0B, 0x33, 0x17, 0x03, 0x3A };
uint8_t t_c09[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x0B, 0x37, 0x21, 0x17, 0x03, 0xA9 };
uint8_t t_c10[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x54, 0xE8, 0x51, 0x17, 0x04, 0xA4 };
uint8_t t_c11[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x29, 0x0D, 0x33, 0x17, 0x03, 0x84 };
uint8_t t_c12[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x4D, 0xFC, 0x20, 0x17, 0x03, 0xDA };
uint8_t t_c13[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x66, 0xB8, 0x51, 0x17, 0x04, 0x7B };
uint8_t t_c14[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x10, 0x41, 0x52, 0x17, 0x04, 0x8C };
uint8_t t_c15[8] = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x92, 0xC3, 0x52, 0x17, 0x04, 0x1A };

// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature.
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 90000;  

//String distr_etaj_temp ;

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int len) {

  String messageTemp;;

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    messageTemp += (char)payload[i];
  }
//Serial.println(messageTemp);
  if (strcmp(topic,"etaj_distr_command") == 0){
    if (messageTemp == "retur_off") {
      relay_off(pinRETUR);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "retur_on") {
      relay_on(pinRETUR);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "pompa_off") {
      relay_off(pinPOMPA);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "pompa_on") {
      relay_on(pinPOMPA);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c01_off") {
      relay_off(pinC01);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c01_on") {
      relay_on(pinC01);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c02_off") {
      relay_off(pinC02);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c02_on") {
      relay_on(pinC02);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c03_off") {
      relay_off(pinC03);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c03_on") {
      relay_on(pinC03);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c04_off") {
      relay_off(pinC04);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c04_on") {
      relay_on(pinC04);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c05_off") {
      relay_off(pinC05);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c05_on") {
      relay_on(pinC05);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c06_off") {
      relay_off(pinC06);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c06_on") {
      relay_on(pinC06);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c07_off") {
      relay_off(pinC07);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c07_on") {
      relay_on(pinC07);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c08_off") {
      relay_off(pinC08);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c08_on") {
      relay_on(pinC08);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c09_off") {
      relay_off(pinC09);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c09_on") {
      relay_on(pinC09);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c10_off") {
      relay_off(pinC10);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c10_on") {
      relay_on(pinC10);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c11_off") {
      relay_off(pinC11);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c11_on") {
      relay_on(pinC11);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c12_off") {
      relay_off(pinC12);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c12_on") {
      relay_on(pinC12);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c13_off") {
      relay_off(pinC13);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c13_on") {
      relay_on(pinC13);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c14_off") {
      relay_off(pinC14);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c14_on") {
      relay_on(pinC14);
    }  
    else if (messageTemp == "c15_off") {
      relay_off(pinC15);
    }
    else if (messageTemp == "c15_on") {
      relay_on(pinC15);
    }  
  }
}

EthernetClient ethClient;
PubSubClient client(ethClient);

void reconnect() {
  while (!client.connected()) {
    if (client.connect("arduinoClient")) {
      client.subscribe("etaj_distr_command");
     } else {
        delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("start");
  sensors.begin();

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(pinC01, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC02, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC03, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC04, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC05, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC06, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC07, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC08, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC09, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC14, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC15, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinC16, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinRETUR, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinPOMPA, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pinC01, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC02, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC03, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC04, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC05, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC06, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC07, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC08, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC09, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC10, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC11, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC12, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC13, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC14, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC15, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinC16, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinRETUR, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinPOMPA, HIGH);

  client.setServer(server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  delay(1500);
}

void relay_on (byte pin){
  digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
  delay(50);
}

void relay_off (byte pin){
  digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
  delay(50);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    get_temps();
  }
client.loop();
}

void get_temps() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  String distr_etaj_temp = String(sensors.getTempC(t_tur_intrare));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_tur));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_retur));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c01));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c02));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c03));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c04));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c05));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c06));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c07));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c08));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c09));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c10));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c11));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c12));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c13));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c14));
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + "|";
  distr_etaj_temp = distr_etaj_temp + String(sensors.getTempC(t_c15));
  int length = distr_etaj_temp.length();
  const char *msgBuffer;
  msgBuffer=distr_etaj_temp.c_str();
  client.publish( "distribuitor-etaj" , msgBuffer ); 
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
```

---

I need some help for optimizing that code (first to make it not crash anymore). I know using String is not ok but was not able to find a way for skip it.
Any help will be highly appreciated
Thank you

Comment: don't use String class

Comment: agree...but i don t know what to use instead String...

Comment: There are countless websites that outline the fundamental differences between programming for microcontrollers with a bytes or a few K of memory and modern microprocessors with many GB of memory.  Learn from these. And if you don't know what String class does internally, you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `String` use C character arrays, for example

```
char foo[MAX_SIZE];
```

Don't call the function `String()` which allocates memory; instead use `strcpy` to copy into the existing character array which you reuse.